# c# drop down results in combobox/textbox while typing

Tags: c#, database, drop-down-menu, combobox, textbox

[Beginner]I have a problem in combobox. When user typing in combobox the similar text in combobox and database will drop down below the combobox.

I need your help, I'm only 1st year college taking up computer science and I have homework. I was given this exercise, and I need to complete it within 2 weeks, but I have only got 3 days to finish it. I don't know how to do this. (sorry to my english)

[Here is the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ0ci.jpg) from youtube search field

Comment: Please have a look at [How do i ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to include relevant information regarding what your Front End (HTML, asp.net mvc, WPF, WinForms,..) is and you should shorten the text about this being your homework. Site guidances states you should not include anything irrelevant to the question (like, for example, greetings). Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/266393

Answer (score 0):

If your using a front end in HTML you can maybe use: Javascript based typeahead

Like this one: https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/